# Connecting iOS App to a database into Label

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, label

I want to connect an my app to the database and display it in a Label.
I could connect my app to the database and display it in the UITableView.

This is what I have so far:

Viewontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CartHistoryViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayDataFromServer;
}


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8888/CartGet.php?  choice=history"];
NSArray *arrayImagesNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

strURL = @"http://localhost:8888/CartGet.php?choice=historydate";
NSArray *arrayImagesPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

// store the result in arrayDataFromServer
arrayDataFromServer = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSEnumerator *enumForNames = [arrayImagesNames objectEnumerator];
NSEnumerator *enumForPahts = [arrayImagesPaths objectEnumerator];

id objName, objPath;

while ( objName = [enumForNames nextObject]) {
    objPath = [enumForPahts nextObject];
    [arrayDataFromServer addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:objName, @"name", objPath, @"path", nil]];
}
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


cell.textLabel.text = [[arrayDataFromServer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
[cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[arrayDataFromServer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"path"];
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayDataFromServer objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"path"]]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


  cell.imageView.image = img;

return cell;
}
```

I want to be able to display it in a Label and in an ImageView instead of a cell. Please help.

Comment: you have an nsmutablearray as a datasource which object in array you want to show in label?

Comment: @SpaceDust objectForKey:@"name"

Comment: what I am asking is lets say you have 3 names in mutablearray = ["tanya", "Lertwichaiworawit" , "jason"]; which one do you want to print in label ? be more clear about what you exactly want!

Comment: @SpaceDust I dont understand your question. I want the label to show what cell.textLabel.text is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your Interface Builder choose your table view and make it `Grouped TableView`

add below code before your `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [arrayDataFromServer count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
   return 0;
}
// set header height of gropued tableview
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
  return 120;//change this value if it is too big
}
//set header section labels
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
      NSString * subject=[[arrayDataFromServer objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"name"];//this line may give you error because of section easy to correct
     UILabel *subjectLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 30, 100, 100)];
     subjectLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/256.0 green:84/256.0 blue:129/256.0 alpha:1.0];
      subjectLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:25];
      subjectLabel.text = subject;
      subjectLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      [subjectLabel sizeToFit];

      // if you want to add image view create an imageview programatically here 

// NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayDataFromServer objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"path"]]];
//NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
//UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
// UIImageView *brickAnim = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];



       // Create header view and add label as a subview choose coordinates wisely
       UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 120, 100, G00)];


        [view addSubview:subjectLabel];
        //[view addSubview:brickAnim];

        return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What is I want to display this Label in a ViewController? I am really new to this, so please help

Comment: so lets make this clear when user click the cell you want bring a detail viewcontroller that is has a label (name) and a bigger image of the cell image?

Comment: No, what I want is very simple, but I dont know how to do it. I want to display "name" in a Label in a ViewController

Comment: so you just want a simple label that has a string "name" in it. Why dont you just drag it in Interface Builder ? @TanyaLertwichaiworawit we have a huge communication problem here for a very simple item :D

Comment: I cant get this line right       NSString * subject=[[arrayDataFromServer objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"name"];

Comment: you need to show me a screen shot or a scratch what exactly  it is do you want. I understand you need a label on viewdidload, but what is gonna be inside of that label?  do you want a label that say NAME or "name value inside of the array" , there might be lots of  "name" values in array do you want to display all of them or just specific one. What is position of the label is going to be ?  on x, y coordinates? you see it is easy to say I want a label, sure go ahead and want one!

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/6g8a34aqn/499b6375/ <- This is a screen capture of my storyboard. I want to display a specific one, not all of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21531/discussion-between-space-dust-and-tanya-lertwichaiworawit)